Omni-channel flow to route to two different queues. Chat button offline
I configured Omni-Channel to work with one queue and it works fine. The problem is that I need two queues for the same routing configuration (kind of Tier 1 and Tier 2 system).
I created the second queue and assigned it to the same routing configuration as the first one. When testing it, it worked fine with agents in Tier 1 but when I put them as busy the chat button changed to "Agent Offline" instead of going to Tier 2.
After reading what how to achieve this I created an Omni-Channel flow and used a decision element so that if an Agent is offline or has more than 1 work item the new chat should be assigned to Tier 2. When I debug the flow it works as expected, the problem is that when I try testing it I have the same issue. Tier 1 agent gets the first chat and runs out of capacity or I set him as busy and after that the button shows "Agent Offline", it never goes to Tier 2.
Any ideas on how I can achieve this?
